# Create Data Access Object in Xcode or MODEL

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Need to create MODEL for following.
I have below Json Response from web service response,

Now i want to create its model so we can easily fetch it something like

```
EmployeeClass.status =
EmployeeClass.statusCode =
EmployeeClass.description =
EmployeeClass.employeeId =

EmployeeClass.Present =
EmployeeClass.Leave =
EmployeeClass.Absent =
EmployeeClass.PFCode=
```

My JSON string is

```
{
    "EmployeeClass": {
        "responseStatus": {
            "status": "SUCCESS",
            "statusCode": "100",
            "description": "Success",
            "employeeId": "1011"
        },
        "Present": 22,
        "Leave": 1,
        "Absent": 4
    },
    "PFCode": "ABC123"
}
```

What i tried so far

Create singleton class EmployeeClass

//------.h class----------------

```
#import < Foundation/Foundation.h >
@interface EmployeeClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString * status ;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString * statusCode ;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString * description ;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString * employeeId ;

@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString * Present ;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString * Leave ;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString * Absent ;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString * PFCode;

+ (EmployeeClass*)sharedSingleton;
@end
```

//----------.m class-----------

```
#import "EmployeeClass.h"

@implementation EmployeeClass
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if(self) {


        self.status = [NSString new];
        self.statusCode = [NSString new];
        self.description = [NSString new];
        self.employeeId = [NSString new];
        self.Present = [NSString new];
        self.Leave = [NSString new];
        self.Absent = [NSString new];
        self.PFCode = [NSString new];


        //do any more customization to your location manager
    }

    return self;
}
+ (EmployeeClass *)sharedSingleton {
    static EmployeeClass *sharedSingleton;
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedSingleton == nil) {
            sharedSingleton = [[EmployeeClass alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return sharedSingleton;
}



@end
```

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: check again please i want to data access object similiar here using singleton

Comment: That's a desire or goal, not a question.  What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly, but you shouldn't do something like `EmployeeClass.property =` because you are trying to access some property stored in a CLASS, and that doesn't make sense. You have to access an **Instance** of that class.

So first you have to retrieve the instance of the singleton: `EmployeeClass *obj = [EmployeeClass sharedSingleton];` and then you can access the properties of the object: `obj.status =`

To parse a JSON string you can do something like this:

```
NSError *error;
NSData *jsondata = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary respObj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
```

So now you have a Dictionary with all the properties. To access the single properties: `[respObj valueForKey:@"anyKey"];`. For Example `obj.status = [respObj valueForKey:@"EmployeeClass"] valueForKey:@"responseStatus"] valueForKey:@"status"]`. This because the first and the second "valueForKey" message will return another NSDictionary.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how to insert my json value in it and then how to retrieve it  using my shared   singleton class

Comment: I edited my response to show you how to parse a json string.

Comment: and how to create model of it?

Comment: Sorry for the late response... what do you mean exactly? In my code and yours we read the json string, we transform it into a dictionary, we store the data into the singleton instance, so we can read it easily. I don't understand what else you want to do with it.

Comment: i want to create 4 different model class then by single singleton class, i want to access them all ?

Comment: ok, so your singleton should not be an EmployeeClass, but maybe a "ModelManager", or "EmployeeManager" that has 4 properties, that point to 4 different instances of the model classes (4 EmployeeClass or other models classes?).

Answer (score 0):

Why create a singleton ?. if you want several employe object. You can't have only one instance of employe. You can check if employeeId is already taken and create a new Employe instead.

For example :

```
Employe *employe = [self getEmployeWithId:employeId];
if (!employe){
    employe = [employe MR_createInContext:yourContext];
    employe.employeId = yourNewId;
}
```